# Add variables from rewrite rules to query var

Tags: plugin-development, permalinks, rewrite-rules

I'm trying to store query variables to a localized variable in the frontend of my plugin. rpSearch shows up like it should but page and share_id are "0" and "" respectively when I test the url with  Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer it looks like it should give me the data i need

[image: screenshot from monkeyman rewrite analyzer]

```
function rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^reseplanerare/dela/([^/]+)/?$','index.php?pagename=reseplanerare&page=share&share_id=$matches[1]', 'top');
    add_rewrite_rule('^reseplanerare/planera/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=reseplanerare&page=plan', 'top');
}

function register_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'page';
    $vars[] = 'share_id';
    return $vars;
}

function public_enqueue_scripts() {
    global $wp_query;
    wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_name,  plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/public/main.js#module', array('jquery'), $this->plugin_ver,true);
    wp_localize_script( $this->plugin_name, 'rpSearch', array(
        'page' => urldecode($wp_query->query_vars['page']),
        'share_id' => urldecode($wp_query->query_vars['share_id'])
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't linking to the page correctly in the rewrite rules. The use of pagename was incorrect instead I should have used page_id. The rewrite rules I ended up using was

```
    add_rewrite_rule('^resa/start/?$', 'index.php?page_id=1897&route_page=start', 'top');
    add_rewrite_rule('^resa/planera/?$', 'index.php?page_id=1897&route_page=plan', 'top');
    add_rewrite_rule('^resa/dela/([^/]+)/?$','index.php?page_id=1897&route_page=share&share_id=$matches[1]', 'top');
```